# JSP import external Class Method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to use an external call method in my jsp file. I want to get an URL to trigger an action. 
on top:

```
<%@ page import="com.myapp.Utils" %>
```

in my body:

```
<form id='externalForm' action="<%= Utils.getWebappURL(request) %>" method="POST" target="_parent">

</form>
```

and I submit the form via JS.

But I get an error message: 
HTTP ERROR: 500

Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
RequestURI=/login
But there are just the header infos.

thx for any help :)

Comment: yes it is a static class. why ?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I meant to say if getWebappURL(request)  is a static method not utils is a static class.Sorry its a mistake

Comment: so i i implement my method into the <head> than i can call `action="<%= getWebappURL(request) %>"`, is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a stack trace in the logs somewhere, have a look at that one.

My conjecture is that the `com.myapp.Utils` isn't on the classpath of your servlet container. The class should be in `WEB-INF/classes` or in a jar in `WEB-INF/lib` (usually, if you've deployed a WAR/exploded WAR).

Cheers,